# Should I use the ++ operator on temporary inline variables?

Tags: c++, c, performance

I was wondering about this pre-mature and not-too-important thing. I have written:

```
m_playerIndex = ++m_playerIndex % 2 // always either 0 or 1 (int)
```

for my chess game to make sure the other player will do the next move after the move that just has been done. However it's not quite readable, is it?

On top of that, it's incrementing a variable by 1, then calling the module operator of 2 on the adapted variable, meaning I have this temporary variable, which I assign to m_playerIndex and immediately after have it replaced by the result of %2. What would be the most efficient? Is it option 2, 1, or is there no difference at all? (I don't have programs to check those things yet.)

1)

```
m_playerIndex = ++m_playerIndex % 2
```

2)

```
m_playerIndex = (m_playerIndex + 1) % 2
```

Comment: In C, option 1 is Undefined Behaviour. (Since C++17, it's well-defined in C++. But I wouldn't use it anyway, because depending on side effect order is unnecessarily confusing for the reader.)

Comment: Option 2 is far better, since it conveys the intent much more clearly than option 1.  Another programmer who looks at the code and saw option 1 would be confused, since it looks like a bug or oversight.  Option 1 needs a comment to inform the subsequent programmer (who may very well be your future self) that the code is not a mistake and intentionally incrementing the m_playerIndex, and then discarding that work.  Also, trust the optimizer (they're amazing), and program for legibility.

Comment: `m_playerIndex = !m_playerIndex;` or `m_playerIndex ^= 1;` if you want to obfuscate the code.

Comment: Dont ask questions tagged C and C++, these are different languages and warrant different answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The expression

```
m_playerIndex = (m_playerIndex + 1) % 2
```

clearly communicates to the reader what is going on. Every slightly possible optimization here is the compiler's job.

Apart from that, for your curiosity, check out https://godbolt.org/ where you can see and compare the assembler instructions created for your code.

Comment: Thanks for that site! Never heard of it, but I will in the future.

Answer (score 3):

You have bigger problems than readability or performance - the behavior of the expression is *undefined*.

You’re attempting to update `m_playerIndex` more than once without an intervening sequence point, through both the `++` and `=` operators.  That’s not guaranteed to do what you expect.

In order for the expression to be well-defined, it needs to be written as

```
m_playerIndex = (m_playerIndex + 1) % 2;
```

It’s not clear to me why you think you need to increment the variable in addition to this, since the result will only ever be `0` or `1`.

Comment: That was to shorten an if-statement (perhaps I should test whether the code is faster as well). I assume the most clear way would be ````if (m_p == 0) {m_p = 1;} else {m_p = 0;}```` (ignoring bit operations)

Comment: @BlayerBond: Not clearer for me, we have to check each branch to know the intent. `m_p = (m_p == 0) ? 1 : 0;` would be better IMO. but `cond ? 1 : 0` is mostly equivalent to `cond`, so `m_p = m_p == 0;` or even `m_p = !m_p;` which conveys less the intend IMO.

Comment: It is clearer indeed, but I rather don't treat integers like Booleans, even though they should only be either 0 or 1, not trying to say the !-operator is for Booleans only, but I only use it for whatever makes sense to me.

Comment: @rici, love it, although it hides the intention even more than anything else I have seen here :)

Comment: @ypnos I guess that depends on the reader. It seems quite clear to me :-) because `x = <constant> - x` is obviously two-state. (You wouldn't complain about `x = -x` if the desired two states were 1 and -1, right?) Some people might prefer `x = x ^ 1` because they learned early that XOR is two-state. But the subtraction comes more naturally to me.

Comment: @rici From my point-of-view it took just a tad longer to read and process it. But if I think about my collegues, who write everything in if-else-constructs, I knew instantly I would not dare to write that at work. P.s.: me personally I am a big fan of the XOR.

Comment: If `m_p` is being used as a Boolean (even if it isn't a proper Boolean type), then `m_p = !m_p` would be idiomatic.  If it's representing one of two not-necessarily-Boolean values, then `m_p = N - m_p` would work better.

Comment: In addition to rici's two state variables; I found a more generalized way for two random integers `a` and `b` with `b > a`: `x = b - (x - a)`.